# Pydantic inconsistent and automatic conversion between float and int

Tags: python, pydantic

I am using pydantic python package in FastAPI for a web app, and I noticed there is some inconsistent float-int conversions with different typing checks.
For example:

```
class model(BaseModel):
    data: Optional[Union[int, float]] = None
m = model(data=3.33)
m.data --> 3.33

class model(BaseModel):
    data: Optional[Union[int, float, str]] = None
m = model(data=3.33)
m.data --> 3

class model(BaseModel):
    data: Union[int, float, str] = None
m = model(data=3.33)
m.data --> 3

class model(BaseModel):
    data: Union[str, int, float] = None
m = model(data=3.33)
m.data --> '3.33'
```

As shown here, different orders/combinations of typings have different behaviors.

I checked out thread https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/360, and https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/284, but they seem not to be the exact same problem.

What causes such behavior under the hood? Is there a specific reason for this? Or did I do anything wrong/inappropriate here?

I'm using python 3.8, pydantic 1.8.2

Thank you for helping!

------ Update ------

In pydantic==1.9.1 this seems has been fixed -> refer to @JacekK's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what happened there we have to know how the Union works and how pydantic uses typing to validate values.

##### Union

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union):

> Union type; Union[X, Y] is equivalent to X | Y and means either X or Y.

**OR** means that at least one element has to be true to make the whole sentence true. So, if the first element is true there's no need to check the second element. Because the whole sentence is true no matter the value of the second element. [Classical disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction#Semantics)

##### Pydantic

Pydantic gets the given value and tries to map it to the type declared in the class attribute definition. If it succeeds then pydantic assigns value to the field. Otherwise it raises a ValidationError.

pseudo code:

```
x.data: int
x.data = "3" # string
x.data = int("3") #convertion,
x.data → 3
```

how it works in your case:

```
x.data = Union[int, float, str]
x.data = 3.33
x.data = int(3.33) #convertion to int, which is first in your Union
# because previous was success, then:
x.data → 3
```

This behavior is known and well [documented](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#unions):

> As such, it is recommended that when defining Union annotations, the most specific type is included first and followed by less specific types.

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    data: Union[float, int, str]


m = MyModel(data=3.33)
print(m.data)
# output is: 3.33

m = MyModel(data="3.33")
print(m.data)
# output is: 3.33

m = MyModel(data=3)
print(m.data)
# output is: 3.0
```

Comment: But if you look at the question again, you'll see that when they defined `data` as `data: Optional[Union[int, float]] = None`, they got a `float` instead of an `int`. (If you have trouble replicating that, try annotating something completely unrelated as `Optional[Union[float, int]]` before defining the model.) Picking a specific union order isn't enough if the union is embedded in another type. (The pydantic docs you linked have a warning about that.)

Comment: Thanks for answering! This explanation makes a lot sense. And I think this is correct in pydantic>=1.9, so I marked this as accepted. Previously`Optional[Union[int, float]] = None` produces `model(data=3.33)=3.33` as in the first example, which doesn't follow this explanation, as @user2357112 mentioned.